# My Address will be changed soon and I have not received my Blue Card yet -Germany

Tags: germany, blue-card

My Address will be changed soon(Less than 2 weeks) and I have not received my Blue Card yet.
The Blue Card will be posted to my address. It's a probability that they post the card to my current address at the last residence day and then the address is not valid anymore.
What will happen then? How can I get my card?

Comment: If the decision about the Blue Card was already made and you are only worried about postal issues, just pay for the post redirect to your new address at Deutsche Post, that's it.

Comment: Thank you @AndreySapegin, the problem is that I have not found my new apartment yet and it will be last seconds hopefully!  So I do not have any new address yet and for the redirect service it needs at least 5 days before hand.
Can I redirect it to my friends address?